# Wowza Media Server Live Video Streaming Delay for IOS devices?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ios5, wowza

Wowza Media Server running Live Video Streaming.

When I view the live video using RTMP and HLS streaming using wowza examples which has live video players for Flash and IOS. I am able to view video for both but whenever the camera is moved rtmp url shows live video without any delay but HLS stream shows the delay of 10 seconds.

Then I tried running a mobile application using cordova(phonegap) for ios devices. I am using HTML video tag in cordova application and I am able to view live video on IPad simulator using HLS streaming but whenever the camera moves there is a delay of 25 seconds while viewing the live video on IPad.

Can someone please let me know what configuration needs to be done on Wowza Server Side to reduce this delay in Live video streaming for IOS devices?

And also can someone please advice any other player other then HTML Video tag for cordova application?

Answer (score 5):

Three chunks are required by iOS devices for streaming to begin. Each chunk is set to 10 seconds by default.If you use a keyframe interval of 1 frame per second you can lower the cupertinoChunkDurationTarget to 1 second(1000) and get the latency down to closer to 3 seconds.

Please check here for more : http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?88-Cupertino-Streaming-segmenter-parameters-%28iOS